# Storing geocode data - lookup performance

Tags: database-design, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

So I'm using google maps api and I want to store the geocodes temporarily so I'm not making the same call over and over. My question is how should I structure my table for best performance.

Should my api input be like my primary key (ex: '123 fake st, new york, ny 12345')?
I'm mainly doing US address, how bad is it to do like a 4 part key(address, city, state, zip)?
Other ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would not make your primary key the whole address, considering how many different ways to write an address. Standard (basic) address decomposition is:

Street
Secondary Address Unit (e.g., floor, bldg.)
City
State
Postal Code
Secondary Postal Code (e.g., the 1234 part of 97123-1234)

More detailed decomposition for address matching is to further break down street:

Street Number
Street Name
Street Type (e.g., Ave, Ct)
Street Direction (e.g., NW, SE)

Here's a link to a description on how to do address reduction for matching US mailing addresses that I wrote a couple of years ago:
http://www.nwstartups.com/api/doc/middleware.php#streetR

Comment: Awesome blog post.  This may be overkill for Evan's needs.  Indexing the cache by the exact address requested (perhaps normalized for casing and whitespace) may be enough if the addresses are almost always unique.  Moreover if his cache TTL is a long duration.

Comment: Yes this is overkill, since my addresses will always just be street, city, state, zip. But cool post.